# Origin of character returns a factor and combining different classes

Tags: r

I've some questions related to the behaviour/properties of the different classes.

When trying to create a data frame with a column of class character it creates a data frame with a factor.

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1= character())
str(df1)
```

Which is the same as

```
df2 <- data.frame(var1= factor())
str(df2)
```

Why isn't the class in the first case `chr`?

When trying to add a time variable an error occurs combined with a for instance a character.
This works:

```
df3 <- data.frame( var1=as.POSIXct(0,origin="2012-12-31"))
str(df3)
```

This doesn't:

```
df4 <- data.frame(var1= character(0),var2=as.POSIXct(0,origin="2012-12-31"))
str(df4)
```

But these do:

```
df4.1 <- data.frame(var1= character(1),var2=as.POSIXct(0,origin="2012-12-31"))
str(df4.1)

df4.2 <- data.frame(var1= factor(0),var2=as.POSIXct(0,origin="2012-12-31"))
str(df4.2)
```

It seems that the behaviour is related to the absence of a level or format (which are present with factor or date classes) with character, numeric and integer classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` is default when creating a `data.frame`. Changing it gets the result you expect.

```
> df1a <- data.frame(var1= character())
> str(df1a)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ var1: Factor w/ 0 levels: 
> df1b <- data.frame(var1= character(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> str(df1b)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ var1: chr
```

For your second one, `character(0)` and `factor(0)` are different things. `character()` is the same as `character(0)`, but `factor()` is not the same as `factor(0)`

Try this:

```
> a <- character()
> b <- character(0)
> A <- factor()
> B <- factor(0)
> sapply(list(a=a, b=b, A=A, B=B), length)
a b A B 
0 0 0 1
```

---

Specifically, from `?character`, usage is in the form of:

```
character(length = 0) ## Just the one argument
```

while from `?factor`, usage is in the form of:

```
factor(x = character(), levels, labels = levels,
       exclude = NA, ordered = is.ordered(x))
```

where the first item is the values that you are going to use to create your factors.

Answer (score 2):

Read `help(data.frame)`.

`df1`: This behaviour is controlled by the `stringsAsFactors` parameter.

`df4`: `var1` is of length 0, `var2`of length 1. All columns in a data.frame must have the same length. Normally, the shorter vector would be recycled, but that's not possible with a vector of length 0.

`df4.2`: `factor(0)` does not return a factor variable of length 0, but a factor with value 0. So both columns are of equal length.